# How to cleanly pass down keyword args?

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyword-argument

When writing functions that call other sub-functions I often want to allow the caller to pass in arbitrary keyword arguments for those subfunctions. However, the current way that I implement this is messy and I am looking for a more clear, concise, and maintainable way.

Below is an example of how I currently implement this:

```
def foo(a, print_line="Hello World!"):
    print a, print_line

def bar(a, number=2, multiple=4):
    print a, number * multiple

def baz(a, **kwargs):
    if "print_line" in kwargs:
        foo(a, print_line=kwargs["print_line"])
    else:
        foo(a)

    bar_kwargs = dict()
    if "number" in kwargs:
        bar_kwargs["number"] = kwargs["number"]
    if "multiple" in kwargs:
        bar_kwargs["multiple"] = kwargs["multiple"]
    bar(a, **bar_kwargs)
```

This method is error-prone and I need to implement every kwarg that I want to express. I can sometimes get away with `foo(a, print_line=kwargs.get("print_line", False)` but I would like to preserve the default argument of the kwarg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. just pass the kwargs themselves into the sub function and add a kwargs variable to the sub functions

```
def foo(a, print_line="Hello World!", **kwargs):
    print a, print_line

def bar(a, number=2, multiple=4, **kwargs):
    print a, number * multiple

def baz(a, **kwargs):
    foo(a, **kwargs)
    bar(a, **kwargs)
```

This works because now the sub functions can receive an arbitrary number of keyword arguments while concretely defining the arguments they are required to have. Thus, a kwarg dict that looks like `{'print_line':'test_line', 'number':1,'multiple':2}` will function perfectly for both functions.

As requested by comment:

```
class SomeoneElsesClass:
  def someone_elses_function(self, a, foo="bar"):
    print(foo)

class MyClass(SomeoneElsesClass):
  def someone_elses_function(self, a, foo="bar2", **kwargs):
    super(MyClass, self).someone_elses_function(a, foo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there some way I can do something similar for functions that I don't control (i.e. from an external library)?

Comment: you can override them. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the keyword arguments for each sub-function in the main function, let the sub-functions handle that logic themselves. This allows you to clearly [separate each concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) in your program.

```
def foo(a, **kwargs):
    print a, kwargs.get('print_line', 'Hello World')

def bar(a, number=2, multiple=4):
    print a, kwargs.get('number', 2) * kwargs.get('multiple', 4)

def baz(a, **kwargs):
    foo(a, **kwargs)
    bar(a, **kwargs)
```

You would then call `baz` like so, only having to pass in specific keyword argument values if you want the keyword argument to have different value than the default:

```
baz('a', print_line='Hello World', number=2, multiple=4)
# or...
baz('a', number=2, multiple=4)
# or...
baz('a', print_line='Hello World')
# or...
baz('a')
```